# Create edges between objects' nearest points with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, splines

[image]

I'm able to create edges between vectors in a random point cloud (the cubes), and the points on a spline. But the connections are not optimal - I assume they're matched up by index - and thus overlap messily.

How can I draw optimal, shortest-distance connections between the point cloud (cubes) and points on the spline?
Bonus points if each point cloud vector is matched to a unique point on the spline (ie. each spline point is connected to only one point cloud vector).

I suspect a KD Tree may be a good approach, considering it has a 'nearest point' function, but my few attempts weren't successful.

[image: Connecting points to circle]
[image: Animation nodes]

Comment: i think the node which are you looking for is "Find shortest path". This should help.